# SQL Server Agent Log error: Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

Last week we had performed the windows patching activity and after the windows patch we confirmed that everything is fine on the SQL server.
All the databases were accessible and all the databases were ONLINE.
All the SQL Server Services were up and running.
SQL Server Agent was also fine.

Then later on when we were looking for the latest database backups.; we could not find any backups even though there was a maintenance plan for the same.

So we decided to do an RCA why the scheduled backups were not happening on the server?
We started checking the SQL Server Error Log / Windows Log / Application Log but could not find anything.

**Finally when checked the SQL Server Agent's Log we found the following errors in it which were repeated continuously for 3 days:**

> [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'... [298]
>   SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>   (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer Error: 10004, Communication
>   link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer
>   Error: 16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>   (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover
>   database 'msdb'... [298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication link
>   failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer
>   Error: 10004, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>   (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication
>   link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [393] Waiting
>   for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'... [298] SQLServer Error:
>   16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>   (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer Error: 10004, Communication
>   link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer
>   Error: 16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>   (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover
>   database 'msdb'... [298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication link
>   failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer
>   Error: 10004, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>   (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer Error: 16389, Communication
>   link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [393] Waiting
>   for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'... [298] SQLServer Error:
>   16389, Communication link failure [SQLSTATE 08S01]
>   (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer Error: 233, Communication link
>   failure [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [298] SQLServer
>   Error: 233, Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of
>   the pipe. [SQLSTATE 08S01] (ConnCheckIfDBIsOnline) [393] Waiting for
>   SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...

My machine details are as follows:

**Windows server:** Windows server 2016

**SQL Server Version:** Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

> **Can anyone let us why the SQL Server Agent was not showing offline / how did the SQL Server went into an ONLINE state whilst in the SQL Server
>   Agent Log it was showing "Waiting for SQL Server to Recover the
>   MSDB...". Also we check the SQL Server services status on daily basis
>   through "sys.dm_server_services" DMV but it never showed us that the
>   SQL Server Agent was not up and Running.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run "SELECT @@SERVERNAME". Do you get an expected result?

Comment: Yes. The result is fine.

Comment: We have restarted the SQL Server Agent and then it started working fine but still could not find out the root cause for this.

Comment: I got the same problem with @KundanDasange, and the workaround is restart the SQL Server Agent services too.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the workaround we have added an alert for this string in the log as it can indicate msdb is not recovered and got hung up.  If you see more than 1 count of that in a timespan, it's worth checking to see if agent is hung.
In the meantime if you don't have an agent, you won't have your jobs and so you won't know if they succeed or fail, which normal 'look for fails' logic can miss.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).